# Why does MATLAB set the Method Attributes of built-in methods to 'Hidden'?

Tags: matlab, oop, methods

['empty'](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/empty.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_empty) is matlab built-in method."At the bottom of [the documentation page](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/empty.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_empty), it is mentioned: 'empty is a hidden, public, static method of all nonabstract MATLAB® classes.''

There is a question, if user build a classes method,for certain reasons, users may want to set a class method as 'Hidden' to prevent others from seeing it. However, in the case of MATLAB built-in methods, everyone is aware of their existence. *So, what's the purpose of MATLAB setting the [Attributes](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-attributes.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_%25E6%2596%25B9%25E6%25B3%2595%25E7%2589%25B9%25E6%2580%25A7) of this method as 'Hidden'?"*

If you input   mc=?SubClass  in command line and open mc-->MethodList in workspace,you will find two method, one is 'SubClass' ,another is 'empty'.*In fact, the 'empty' method isn't completely hidden, so what's the significance of setting a built-in method to 'Hidden'?"*

```
classdef  SubClass < Base
    methods
        function obj=SubClass(value)
            obj=obj@Base(value);
        end
    end
end
```

Base.m

```
classdef Base
    properties(Access=private)
        a;
    end
    methods
        function obj=Base(value)
            obj.a=value;
        end
    end
    methods (Access=private)
        function Fun(obj)
            disp(num2str(obj.a));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before using them, this question is not related to `matlab-guide` or `matlab-deployment`. As to your question, it's only answerable by whoever made that decision at MathWorks in 2007, and otherwise is pretty much just going to attract opinion-based answers

Comment: My guess is that the built-in methods are hidden to not clutter the `methods` output for the class, and the documentation. It has no other effect. You can explicitly define the method to have it listed.